# Custom submit handler on node form not picked up

Tags: forms

I am altering a node form with hook_form_alter and adding a couple of submit handlers. When the form gets submitted they get picked up using:

```
foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
  if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
    array_unshift($form['actions'][$action]['#submit'], 'submit_handler_a');
    $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'submit_handler_b';
  }
}
```

Problem is, if the form contains a field that can store multiple values, as soon as I click on the 'Add more' button for that field and a new value for it, when submitting the form my handlers are not being picked up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change hook_form_alter to hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter to make it work. My code ended up looking like:

```
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) 
{
  if ($form['#form_id'] == 'node_mycontettype_form') {
    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
      if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
        array_unshift($form['actions'][$action]['#submit'], 'submit_handler_a');
        $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'submit_handler_b';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My custom handlers are now being picked after a multiple value field submits multiple values. I don't know why this made the difference and can't find anything in the docs, but I hope this helps people that run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on those form elements in the form array. They might have their own ['#submit'] in the array and you might need to add your custom handler on those too